# Export to Word from ASP

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic, content-type

i am working in an old application developed using classic ASP and VB, i am trying to export an HTML table from an asp page to word, i searched the internet for this and i found a good code that its working perfectly, he problem is that it export the whole page to word, i need to export only a part of the page which is the `<table></table>`

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<%
Option Explicit
Response.Buffer = TRUE
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-word"
Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename = MyDoc.doc"
%>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<%
Dim Conn,strSQL,objRec
Set Conn = Server.Createobject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Open "DRIVER=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb);DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("shotdev/mydatabase.mdb"),"" , ""
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM customer "
Set objRec = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objRec.Open strSQL, Conn, 1,3
%>
<table width="600" border="1">
<tr>
<th width="91"> <div align="center">CustomerID </div></th>
<th width="98"> <div align="center">Name </div></th>
<th width="198"> <div align="center">Email </div></th>
<th width="97"> <div align="center">CountryCode </div></th>
<th width="59"> <div align="center">Budget </div></th>
<th width="71"> <div align="center">Used </div></th>
</tr>
<%
While Not objRec.EOF
%>
<tr>
<td><div align="center"><%=objRec.Fields("CustomerID").Value%></div></td>
<td><%=objRec.Fields("Name").Value%></td>
<td><%=objRec.Fields("Email").Value%></td>
<td><div align="center"><%=objRec.Fields("CountryCode").Value%></div></td>
<td align="right"><%=objRec.Fields("Budget").Value%></td>
<td align="right"><%=objRec.Fields("Used").Value%></td>
</tr>
<%
objRec.MoveNext
Wend
%>
</table>
<%
objRec.Close()
Conn.Close()
Set objRec = Nothing
Set Conn = Nothing
%>      
</body>
</html>
```

[you can check the link here](http://www.shotdev.com/asp/asp-word/asp-word-response-contenttype-application-vnd-ms-word/)

can you please help me to solve this issue
thank you

Comment: What else is there on the page apart from the table? Can only see the table in body..

Comment: yeah i posted the original code, but when i add a forms fields and then a button to click for exporting it will export also the form fields and the buttons

Comment: Whatever is after the `Response.contenttype` line will be shown in the doc. If you want only the details from the db to be shown, you will have to show the table in a different page with the contenttype set.

Comment: Using an iframe might help here.

Comment: Just add a variable that indicates if you are in browser mode of word mode, and put it around anything you don't want showing up in your word version.